# What is your screenshot tool and your experience in handling the screenshot requirements for the apple app store?

Tags: swift, xcode7

Now I am trying to submit my first app to apple store. The screenshots requirement gives me headache. I just use the simulator and the command+shift+4 to capture the screenshots. Unfortunately, the apple store told me that the dimensions of the screenshots are wrong. But I already ensure the size is correct. for example, for the 3. 5 inch one, it is 640960, yes, my screenshot is 640960. What went wrong? Or do I need a professional screenshot tool for capture the screenshots? Your recommendation will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried https://launchkit.io/screenshots?

Comment: Look into the menu of the simulator. It has an option to create a screenshot as PNG. It creates the correct size. Or do it on the device...

Comment: Thank Shripada and MirekE21. I will review the launchikit software. Yes, I already used the command+S to capture the screenshots.

Comment: I use the simulator to take the screenshots. CMD+S will take screenshots without having to click through the menu bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a pain. 
What I do is take the screenshots in the simulator on a 6plus (cmd + s). Than you can use something like pixelmator to scale them for the smaller devices.

For iPads this works too although the images will appear slightly squashed since the iPad is not widescreen. In my experience however it's not that bad and is better than taking extra screenshots for the iPad.

Don't even ask about the videos, that's the biggest pain.